# cas authentication through different web browsers affects extra user attributes

Tags: cas

I have recently encountered one interesting behaviour. 
If I authenticate through Chrome I don't get any extra user attributes I specified in config.

```
Assertion is not null
No attributes found
```

However, if I do the same thing with Firefox I receive attributes as expected.

```
Assertion is not null
Attribute number is greater than 0
CAS Attr Key: id
CAS Attr Value: 3500
CAS Attr Key: email
CAS Attr Value: username@mail.io
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what is causing it? Is it a bug?

Comment: for people, who might experience similar problems. Today we discovered that when you login using user name in different cases like user1 and User1, you still pass authorization, but only get extra attributes if user name coincides with the one stored in DB (comparison to used in org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao is case sensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute release does not directly involve the browser. It is strictly client application server to CAS application server communication. The fact that the missing attributes coincide with a specific browser version indicates that there might be a flaw in the logic somewhere else in the client application.

You didn't indicate what CAS Client you are using, so no additional advice can be given.